# Why compilation fails ?

Tags: java

Why does compilation fails in this case ?

Is this what happened ? :  constructor of `Employee` calls `default constructor of Person` and that's all.

[image]

Comment: this is not a homework, I really need your help.

Comment: What happened when you tried it and when you looked up the error what did you find?

Comment: compilation really fails , with a bunch of errors http://ideone.com/5gHWyr

Comment: If this is not a homework, it must be some sort of a test :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight OCPJP test in training mode.

Comment: @ALJIMohamed "compilation really fails , with a bunch of errors" That's because you did not copy the code correctly. In addition, ideone puts some restrictions on what you can do, so the person and employee classes should be nested. Here is your code with the real problem reported: http://ideone.com/okoiFg

Comment: @ALJIMohamed That's because you code is not the same as the code in your example.  Make the code the same and you should get one error.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight and if you google that error message you get 975,000 results.

Comment: @PeterLawrey 975K??? Wow, I think the message is self-explanatory... On the other hand, considering the volume of "plz send codes" questions on SO alone, I shouldn't be overly surprised.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight lolz Allot of the first page were stack overflow ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call a constructor in Person when constructing an Employee. By default, the compiler will call the default constructor (with no arguments), but in this case, it doesn't exist in Person (the compiler creates a default constructor only if no other constructor exists).

You must call to a concrete constructor of Person in the first line of Employee constructor, or defining a default constructor in Person.

Answer (score 7):

as your super class constructor doesn't have an no-args default constructor defined, you should explicitly make a call to your super-class's 1-args constructor from your sub-class constructor.
Thus Answer is **D** compilation error on line 18

To fix the code:

```
public Employee(String id){
super("pass person name");
//rest of the code
}
```

Comment: but I don't need to do that, I found an alternative using `empID` string ! why the compilation does not succeed ?

Comment: well, if your Person name is an EmpId then that would do it .. :), it was only a sample code by the way.. :)

Comment: you still not answered my question ! Why the compilator **TALK** in this case. for 'him' it will create two default constructor and that's all ... ?!

Comment: @ALJIMohamed default-constructor is not included by the compiler if you write a constructor in your code. i.e., in your case in both the class's compiler did not create any default constructor for you as you have written your own constructor .

Comment: so since I have constructor for _Person_ and _Employee_ , no default Constructor will be created. Thus, when I allocate space with `new Employee` I need to call a _default constructor_ for _Person_ which does not exist ! that's why compilation fails ?! right :)

Comment: well, not exactly, with the current code at hand, you can simply user super() to call the 1-args constructor of your super class as show in my code smaple. i recommend you to read about constructor -overloading and use of super in constructor. :) good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be assuming Person has a default constructor. The compiler only inserts a default constructor if there is no declared constructor. If you want Person to have a no-arg constructor you need to declare one.